# iOS Pong Development, Collision Detection

Tags: objective-c, ios, collision-detection

I am in a late phase of finishing my first usable iOS app.
I am creating a simple Pong game i am using a simple collision detection using `CGRectIntersectsRect`, but i came up with a problem.

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(mic.frame,plosina_a.frame)) {
        if(mic.center.y < (plosina_a.center.y + plosina_a.frame.size.height)) {
            RychlostMice.y = -RychlostMice.y;
        }
    }
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(mic.frame,plosina_b.frame)) {
        if(mic.center.y < (plosina_b.center.y + plosina_b.frame.size.height)) {
            RychlostMice.y = -RychlostMice.y;
        }
    }
```

When i use it like this the ball (mic) sort of gets to the paddles (plosina) and starts moving the other way sort of in the middle of the paddle.
My programming teacher managed to fix this problem for one of the paddles (the _b one) by adding the .frame.size.height instead of just .frame which i have used before, but when i did the same thing for the other paddle it didn't work i don't know what's up with that.

Also it creates another problem sometimes there is a situation where the ball get's caught up in the paddle - so I'm looking for a definition of the whole object and not just one side probably?

i hope you can help.

Comment: is _a paddle at the top and _b paddle at bottom? if so maybe try reversing what you did with _b.frame.size.height for paddle _a if that makes sense

Comment: no _a is on the bottom of the game field and _b is on the top.

Comment: still try reversing it so as I think Nick Lockwood is suggesting use `-` instead of `+`

Comment: im not sure, but i think it doesn't change anything if i reverse the with the be, the _b will still be the one which works well.

Answer (score 2):

I can see three potential problems here.

The first is that you are waiting until the ball overlaps the paddle before counting it as a touch. It sounds like you really want to start the ball moving in the other direction when the ball touches the paddle, not when it intersects it. The CGRectIntersectsRect waits until they overlap before returning true. If you make either rectangle one pixel larger with a call to CGRectInset, your test will return true as soon as the ball reaches that paddle--by that time, there will be one pixel overlapping the expand rectangle. The test would look like this:

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRectInset(mic.frame, -1, -1),plosina_a.frame)) {
    if(mic.center.y < (plosina_a.center.y + plosina_a.frame.size.height)) {
        RychlostMice.y = -RychlostMice.y;
    }
}
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRectInset(mic.frame, -1, -1),plosina_b.frame)) {
    if(mic.center.y < (plosina_b.center.y + plosina_b.frame.size.height)) {
        RychlostMice.y = -RychlostMice.y;
    }
}
```

The second potential problem has to do with the velocity of the ball. Without seeing all of the code, I don't know if this is a problem or not. If the ball can move more than one pixel at a time, it could easily overlap--or even pass through--the paddle without a hit detection. There are lots of logic changes you can add to take care of this, but the easiest solution may be to just make sure the ball doesn't move more than one pixel at a time.

Finally, if you want to use the hack for both paddles, reverse the sign of the comparison on the other side of the game.

Comment: Ok im not sure if it can move more than one pixel at a time I'm giving the ball a velocity via CGPointMake and I'm giving it a speed for X and Y axis.
Either way when i use the CGRectInset it detects the ball before overlapping which CGRectIntersectsRect doesn't?

Comment: I reversed the comparison sign and it makes the _b paddle work properly (or how i think it should work), but the _a paddle still looks like the ball is overlapping

Comment: Take a look at the equation for moving the ball--it's probably something like x = x + dx, and similar for y. If abs(dx) can be greater than 1, you can move it more than one pixel at a time.

Comment: I have a CGPoint of the Ball Velocity.. I'm giving it a float for x and y `CGPoint BallVelocity = CGPointMake(BallVelocityX, BallVelocityY);`
the values for the floats are defined, each is bigger than 1, and to be honest I never really find out what exactly does it mean if it's moving for that number of pixels each time or something else.. (you are working here with a pure n00b, sorry), but i don't see what could be the equation to find out if it's bigger than 1 or not.

Comment: What code are you using to update the ball position? Is the value you add or subtract larger that 1?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your pong is played vertically, so that one paddle is at the top of the screen and the other is at the bottom?

If you you need to mirror the logic vertically for the other paddle. Right now you are using the same logic for the top and bottom paddles, but for the bottom paddle you probably need something like the following instead

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(mic.frame,plosina_b.frame)) {
    if(mic.center.y > (plosina_b.center.y - plosina_b.frame.size.height)) {
        RychlostMice.y = -RychlostMice.y;
    }
}
```

Notice how I'm using the > sign and subtracting the height instead of adding it.

Comment: well plosina_b is the one which somehow works.. if i do what you say it will still work, but if i apply that to the plosina_a it just won't work.. i tried reversing the > sign and subtract, but if i use subtract in the plosina_a collision detection it will just simply go through.

Comment: And still it doesn't fix the problem with the ball getting stuck inside the paddle sometime.